# Horizontal equivalents of Above / Below for labeling bar charts?

Tags: graphics, labeling, charts

**NB:** For this post, I'll use ***bar's end*** as shorthand for ***the end of the bar that's opposite to the bar's origin***.

---

In bar charts, the `Above` symbol can be used to position labels right outside the bar's end:

```
BarChart[{531, 29, 1869}
 , ChartLabels -> {"A", "B", "C"}
 , LabelingFunction -> Above
 , ImageSize -> Small
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If `BarOrigin -> Top`, one can get the corresponding effect by using `Below` instead of `Above`:

```
BarChart[{531, 29, 1869}
 , ChartLabels -> {"A", "B", "C"}
 , BarOrigin -> Top
 , LabelingFunction -> Below
 , ImageSize -> Small
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

How can one achieve the same effect when `BarOrigin -> Left` or `BarOrigin -> Right`?

---

To be clear about the desired effect, when `BarOrigin -> Left` (resp. `BarOrigin -> Right`), the label should be placed to the right (resp. to the left) of the bar, just outside the bar's end.  The label's text should be left-justified (resp. right-justified), but it should have the same font, size, *and orientation* is it does when `LabelingFunction -> Above`.

Comment: Have you tried `LabelingFunction -> After`?

Comment: Regarding the question you deleted: I was hoping to see an answer to it (after specifying the context where Placed is used). I think it would have been a useful Q/A ....

Comment: @Szabolcs: FWIW, I undeleted the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `LabelingFunction` with `After` sets the labels to the rightside of the bar.

```
BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> {"A", "B", "C"}, BarOrigin -> Left, 
LabelingFunction -> After, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Similarly, to get the labels before the bar, use `LabelingFunction -> Before`.